# Abstract Algebra: Question on Centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is a group and the centralizer of a subgroup $H$ is

$Z_G(H) = \{g ∈ G;\ ∀h ∈ H\ gh = hg\}$

$S$ is any subset of $Z_G(H)$

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that $H = Z_G(S)$

It seems obvious that $∀h ∈ H,\  h ∈ Z_G(S)$

However, I cannot prove the opposite direction. Is it possible that there is an element of $G$ outside of $H$ that commutes with every element in $S$? Thank you for reading!

Comment: Consider for example the set consisting of only the identity.

Comment: I see. So a set S consisting of only the identity element commutes with all the elements of G. That means Zg(S) = G and this is not always the same as H. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other direction is obviously false.

For example, let H be $\{e\}$, which is the trivial subgroup of $G$. 
 $Z_G(H)$ would be the whole group $G$.

Let $S$ be $Z_G(H)= G$ itself. If your assertion was true, $G$ would have a trivial center. Since there is no restriction on $G$, let $G$ be any abelian group would contradict it.